# Localization as dual to quotienting?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory, duality-theorems, localization

Why does localization look so close to quotienting? Consider the ismorphism theorem:

> For a ring map $\phi: R_1 \rightarrow R_2$, let $\ker\phi \equiv \{ r_1\in R_1 : \phi(r_1) = 0 \}$. Then, $\ker \phi$ is an ideal of $R_1$, and there exists an epi-mono factorization of $\phi$ into $R_1 \twoheadrightarrow R_1 /\ker\phi \hookrightarrow R_2$  where $\hookrightarrow$ is injective and $\twoheadrightarrow$ is surjective.

Now consider the similar theorem for localization, where I denote by $R  \hat \times S \equiv S^{-1}R$ for notational suggestivity. Now I write down:

> For a ring map $\psi : R_1 \rightarrow R_2$, Let $\operatorname{rek}\psi \equiv \{ r_1 \in R_1 : \psi(r_1) = 1 \}$. Then $\operatorname{rek}\psi$ is a multiplicative subset of $R_1$ and there exists a mono-epi factorization of $\psi$ into $R_1 \hookrightarrow R_1 \hat \times \psi \twoheadrightarrow R_2$

I can build a table:

- $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$.
- $\ker \leftrightarrow\operatorname{rek}$.
- injection $\leftrightarrow$ surjection.
- $/ \leftrightarrow \hat\times$
- ideal $\leftrightarrow$ multiplicative subset.
- $0 \leftrightarrow 1$.

to convert from the quotienting into localization. Is there some "deep" going on here for this duality? This $0 \leftrightarrow 1$ business makes me hopeful that there might be something deeper / categorical lurking in the background.

EDIT: I had only commutative rings in mind when I wrote this. Please feel free to take assumptions on $R$ as required (Commutative, Noetherian, for example), if that allows us to explain this "duality".

Comment: I'm not convinced that the claimed mono-epi factorization exists. Right adjoints preserve monomorphisms, so the forgetful functor $\mathbf{CRing}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$ had better send monomorphisms to injective functions, but localizations are certainly not always injective. I'm also strongly skeptical that the claimed epi is epic. I don't think the duality holds in the generality you claim, but (for good enough, commutative rings) the first factorization corresponds to factoring the map of schemes into a dominant map and a closed immersion, and the second sort of looks like a locally closed imm.

Comment: I have only seen elementary examples of localizations as they occur in $\mathbb R[X_1, \dots X_n]$ and these have been mono-epi. I had convinced myself with an argument that it always ought to be epi, but perhaps I am wrong. Should I split this off into a separate question? (does localization on comm. rings induce mono-epi factorization?)

Comment: Regarding schemes, I have not gotten that far yet, sadly, so I don't know the objects you are referring to (schemes / closed immersions / locally closed immersions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fabio gives a very nice answer to your question, but doesn't directly address an important point of confusion in your original post/comments, so I'm adding this answer for posterity. In general, a map $\psi:R_1\rightarrow R_2$  will absolutely *not* induce an epimorphism $\text{rek}(\psi)^{-1}R_1\twoheadrightarrow R_2$, even if we take the stronger definition $\text{rek}(\psi)=\psi^{-1}(R_2^\times)$ given by Fabio. For instance, if every element of $\text{rek}(\psi)$ is already a unit in $R_1$, then we will just have $\text{rek}(\psi)^{-1}R_1=R_1$, and so using this it is easy to come up with examples where the induced map is not epi.

For instance, take $R_1=\mathbb{Q}$, and $R_2$ any field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with a non-trivial automorphism $\alpha$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ pointwise, with $\psi:R_1\hookrightarrow R_2$ the inclusion map. Then $\text{rek}(\psi)=\mathbb{Q}^\times$ , so $\text{rek}(\psi)^{-1}\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}$ and the induced map to $R_2$ is just $\psi$, which is certainly not an epimorphism. (E.g. $\alpha\circ\psi=\text{id}_{R_2}\circ\psi$ but $\alpha\neq\text{id}_{R_2}$).

Indeed, the polynomial ring example you give in the comments of your post does not hold in general either. If we let $R_1=\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $R_2=\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, with $\psi:R_1\hookrightarrow R_2$ again the inclusion map, then once again $\text{rek}(\psi)=R_1^\times$ but $\psi$ is certainly not epi.

The problem in all of these examples is that $R_2$ can be very big compared to the image of $R_1$; hopefully the above examples clarify that point. (Note however, that – provided $R_2\neq\{0\}$ – the map $R_1\hookrightarrow \text{rek}(\psi)^{-1}R_1$ will *still* be injective, even if we use Fabio's stronger definition of $\text{rek}(\psi)$, because no element of $\text{rek}(\psi)$ can be a zero-divisor in $R_1$.)

Answer (score 5):

The deeper / categorical lurking in the background is the notion of factorization structure.
Let $E$ and $M$ be two classes of morphisms in a category.
Then $(E,M)$ is said to be a factorization structure if:

1. $E$ and $M$ are closed under composition with isomorphisms;
2. every ring homomorphism has a factorization $\mu\circ\varepsilon$ with $\mu\in M$ and $\varepsilon\in E$;
3. the unique $(E,M)$-diagonalization property that for every commutative diagram$\require{AMScd}$
   $$\begin{CD}
   A@>\varepsilon>>B\\
   @V\varphi VV @VV\gamma V\\
   C@>>\mu> D
   \end{CD}$$
   with $\varepsilon\in E$ and $\mu\in M$ there exists a unique diagonal $\delta:B\to C$ making the diagram commtative.

---

In the category of commutative rings we have the following factorization structures:

1. $E$ is the class of surjective ring homomorphisms and $M$ the class of injective ring homomorphisms;
2. $E$ be the class of ring localizations, that's of the form (up to
   isomorphism) $A\to S^{-1}A$ where $S\subseteq A$ is a multiplicative
   system of $A$ and $M$ be the class of ring homomorphism $\varrho:A\to B$ such that $A^\times=\varrho^{-1}(B^\times)$;
3. $E$ is the class of integral ring homomorphisms and $M$ is the class of injective and integrally closed ring homomorphisms.

---

Consider the second factorization structure in the list above, every homomorphism of commutative rings $\varrho:A\to B$ has as essentially unique $(E,M)$ factorization
$$A\xrightarrow\varepsilon S^{-1}A\xrightarrow\mu B$$
where $S=\psi^{-1}(R_2^\times)$.
Thus, with your notation, we have to take $\operatorname{rek}(\psi)=\psi^{-1}(R_2^\times)=\{ r_1 \in R_1 : \psi(r_1) \in R_2^\times \}$.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for (3)? I have not seen the notion of an integrally closed ring homomorphism before :)

Comment: I havn't a reference; by integrally closed ring homomorphism I mean a ring homomorphism whose image is integrally closed in the codomain.